# How to show a border around multiple items in android listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to put a border around a group if list items. I have seen several solutions for setting the background of multiple items but can I also draw a border (one square around a group of items)? How could I do that?[image]

Comment: do you want to put the border around consecutive items or some items individually

Comment: I want one square around the group of items, see my image above.